# Visual C#: передача файлов по протоколу SOAP

Tags: c#

Пишу Windows-сервис, который должен передавать на сервер файлы из заданного каталога, а после успешной передачи - стереть их. Решил написать тестовую программу для проверки SOAP-запросов. Я генерировал SOAP-запросы из WSDL-файла. Идентификационный запрос прошел нормально, файлы на сервер ушли тоже без проблем. Проблемы начались в тот момент, когда я стал удалять отосланные файлы. Сначала я пытался удалять их сразу после отсылки и тут же получил исключение

> "Delete Error: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "C:\ElarService\current_sessions\gjeboldov@elar.ru\1.jpg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Тогда я решил удалять файлы после того, как они все отправятся. Посылалось 5 файлов, после чего стал их удалять. В итоге, первые три удалились, а на два последних вывалилось упомянутое выше исключение.
Вот код SOAP-запроса:

```
    public string SaveImage(string SessionID, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")] string NumberPage, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary")] byte[] Image, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")] string FileLength) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("SaveImage", new object[] {
                SessionID,
                NumberPage,
                Image,
                FileLength});
    return ((string)(results[0]));
}
```

Функция, где этот запрос вызывается:

```
        public static int SendFiles()
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(WorkingDir);
        int count = 0;

        IsDelete = 0;
        List.Clear();

        foreach (var name in files)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(name);
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + name);
            ImageConverter conv = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] arr = (byte[]) conv.ConvertTo(img, typeof (byte[]));
            if (arr != null)
            {
                int retCode;

                var answer = Request.SaveImage(SessionId, Convert.ToString(count), arr, Convert.ToString(arr.Length));
                int.TryParse(answer, out retCode);
                Console.WriteLine("In SendFiles foreach result = {0}, count = {1}", retCode, count);
                if (retCode != 1)
                {
                    IsDelete = 1;
                    List.Add(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    List.Add(1);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Функция удаления файлов:

```
        public static void DeleteFiles()
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(WorkingDir);
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {
            if (List[i] == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(files[i]);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delete Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        if (IsDelete == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(WorkingDir);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Directory delete error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну, и, собственно, вопрос: что может блокировать файл? Заранее извините, я в C# человек новый, это мой первый опыт.

P.S. Ставил задержку аж в 10 секунд - не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Image img = Image.FromFile(name);`

Картинка - это неуправляемый ресурс. Поставьте `using`

PS при чем тут вообще SOAP? Магии не бывает, сервер ну никак не может удаленно блокировать файл, пересылаемый в виде массива байт.

Comment: Я просто думал, а вдруг запрос асинхронный? Пригляделся - вроде нет. А не поясните, как этот using использовать? Я новичок в C#

Comment: @HermannZheboldov да даже если асинхронный - к моменту, когда файл только начинает передаваться - он уже массив байт. Массив байт блокировать ничего не может.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov про `using` - почитайте любой учебник!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало!